# Lost changes in a single file after quitting vscode on mac

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

My query is how can we backup the changes we had after quitting the vscode?

My local build was failing, and I was trying to add new files (which didn't turn green), and was unable to stage the changes. So i quit the application. Now when I have reopened the app, all the new files that i added were restored, except for the changes that I made to an existing file on the master branch, they all got reversed. I also tried *git stash pop* git command, but it didn't bring up the changes in that file (I did stash my changes before quitting the app).

What can I do to get back the changes I made in a file?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Could you provide `git stash list` output?

Comment: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        resources/_gen/assets/scss/css/main.scss_e86386c8bae1cd02295de71a1be078d6.content
        resources/_gen/assets/scss/css/main.scss_e86386c8bae1cd02295de71a1be078d6.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.

Comment: I don't think the git stash command worked, since git got crashed and had to close the vscode app. The change that I made was in some file of the menu folder.

Comment: `git stash list` will print your stashes, did you run this command correctly?